# Smartface version 4.3.0 "File Download Upload.sfpx" project

Tags: smartface.io

I am running Smartface version 4.3.0 and have loaded the "File Download Upload.sfpx" project from GitHub smartface/Sample-Projects and receive the following error on both Android and iPhone -

"There has been an unhandled application error, please inform developers"

Can you please tell me where I can download a version that will work with 4.3.0 or tell me what I need to do get the project to work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue about download method.
In the next release, which will be announced soon, it will be fixed.